# Time-invariant systems?

Tags: calculus, physics

I am reading the paper http://web.mit.edu/2.14/www/Handouts/Convolution.pdf because I want to learn about convolutions.
With
$$
\delta_T (t) = \begin{cases} 
      0 & t \leq 0 \\
      1/T & 0 < t \leq T
   \end{cases}
$$
the following is said:

> We now assume that the system response to $\delta_T (t)$ is a known
> function and is designated $h_T (t)$. Then if the system is linear and
> **time-invariant**, the response to a delayed unit pulse, occurring at time nT, is simply a delayed version of the pulse response: $y_n (t) =
> > h_T (t- nT)$

The linear system with the output function $y_n (t)$ is time-invariant. I think I get the definition of being time-invariant(not directly depend on time, possible indirectly from the input function). However, I still have no idea why $y_n (t)$ should be equal to $h_T (t - nT)$ -- like where does the $- nT$ part come from?

If you wanna take a look, it is formula 12 in the paper :))

Answer (score 1):

The system is time-invariant, i.e., if the input is delayed by $\tau$, the output is also delayed by $\tau$, nothing else changes. So, if the response of the system to $\delta(t)$ is $h(t)$, then its response to $\delta(t-nT)$, which is $\delta(t)$ shifted to the right by $nT$, is simply $h(t-nT)$, which is $h(t)$ shifted to the right by $nT$.